# What was the median age at first marriage for women in Britain from 1890 to 1970?

Tags: marriage, statistics, family

I am interested in not the mean but rather in the median. So far, I have had the highest difficulty in attaining any information on this matter for the United Kingdom or Great Britain. Thankfully, the statistics for this are available for the United States from the late 19th century onwards but not for any European country.

For the 1860s, it is well known that the median age for the UK is around 23.5. However, I have not come across any data for the period onwards.

It would be extremely appreciated if someone could provide any information on this matter.

For example, did women marry later in the UK than the US in the 1940s and 1950s? What about nations like Belgium, Holland and West Germany? In general, it would be appreciated if someone confirmed whether (white) women in the US married later or earlier than those in Western European countries generally in the early and mid 20th century.

Comment: Perfect. Three generations in Britain I see as a reasonable scope. I have retracted my close vote in consequence. However, please clarify if you mean **Great Britain** (all islands in the archipelago) or the **United Kingdom of England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland**. The two differ for much of that time period by the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Ah yes, I'd like the possible answer to be suited for Great Britain, with Northern Ireland excluded. However, I have noticed that demographics of this sort relating to GB alone can be difficult to attain, with most only available for UK as a whole. I'd prefer the median ages for the GB only, but if someone provides them for the UK, I would not mind.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91793/discussion-on-question-by-kalis-what-was-the-median-age-at-first-marriage-for-wo).

Comment: I don't have a complete time series on hand, but British ages at first marriage were essentially stable for a century until about 1930. It then fell for 3 decades, reaching ~25 for men and ~23 for women, and then began increasing again essentially ever since. You should be able to get more information from HM Stationery Office's *Demographic Review*.